# Should I use form helpers over standard HTML?

Tags: html, codeigniter, zend-framework, helper

Is it good for performance or security issue to use those class as we know that HTML should be in plain HTML.

Example:

in Codeigniter Framewỏrk:

```
 echo form_input(array('name' => 'one'));
```

is known as

```
<input type="text" name="one"/>
```

Which is better?

Comment: I tend to avoid them as I use a custom template system which allows me to keep all my view files as HTML only, making them more accessible to the designers. If you want to use codeigniters built in csrf tokens, then you will have to use the form helper to open/close the forms but other than that it's mostly down to your own preference I guess.

Comment: @Jeemusu you don't need to use the form helper for CSRF tokens as you can just do this: `<input name='<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>' />`

Comment: @cryptic ツ - Wish I knew that sooner :P Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

**Copied from Phil Sturgeon Blog:**
The extra layer of abstraction, combined with helper extending/overriding makes it very easy to change simple bits of logic throughout your application output with minimal fuss.

To explain, I'll use an example.

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('controller/method'); ?>" method="post">
vrs
<?php echo form_open('controller/method');
```

First you will see the standard `HTML` way to do it, with the `site_url()` function used to create the link to the form action. Second you will see the `form_open()` tag - and in this example its shorter too, wahey!

I wanted a way to set `accept-charset="UTF-8"` in all my forms to help keep my data all [UTF-8 in CodeIgniter](/news/2009/08/UTF-8-support-for-CodeIgniter). 
If I was using just `HTML` then I would have to go through **all** my forms and add that in myself, which would be wasting time I could have spent at the pub.

Instead, as CodeIgniter allows you to extend helpers, I just made my own slightly modified `form_open()` in `application/helpers/MY_form_helper.php` which contained this logic.
Because I was using PHP to wrap my useful data, I could make one simple change and update all of my  tags.

The main problem is people are looking at these `HTML` helper functions and seeing them purely as different syntax.

For complete article visit: 
http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/12/Why-CodeIgniter-HTML-helper-functions-rock

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question.  I think ultimately it comes down to personal preference.  Personally I don't like using the form helpers but I can certainly see the benefits of using them and I do try to use them if I'm working on a big project.  Because like Phil Sturgeon says its a lot easier when you want to make a site wide change to all form fields.

Although I would be interested to see if using the form helper functions affects performance.  Surely using PHP to generate the HTML has a performance hit than just writing the HTML normally?